# Error :"the given key was not present in the dictionary " while creating publishing page in Powershell CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I am facing error:"the given key was not present in the dictionary " while i am creating  publishing page in sharepoint online  using powershell CSOM.

Here is my code:

```
 $subsiteCtx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($subsiteUrl)
            $subsiteCtx.Credentials = $credentials
            $subsiteCtx.ExecuteQuery()
            $subsiteweb=$subsiteCtx.Web  

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl) 
             $ctx.Credentials = $credentials
             $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
             $pageLayoutList = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Master Page Gallery")
             $ctx.Load($pageLayoutList)
             $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

             $pageLayoutQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery  
             $pageLayoutQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type='Text'>"+$pageLayoutName+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"  

             $pageLayouts = $pageLayoutList.GetItems($pageLayoutQuery)  
             $ctx.Load($pageLayouts)  
             $ctx.ExecuteQuery()  
             $pageLayout = $pageLayouts[0]

                 Write-Host $pageLayouts.Count "-" $pageLayout.Id 

             #Get the publishing Web  
             $pubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($subsiteCtx, $subsiteCtx.Web)  
             $subsiteCtx.Load($pubWeb)    
             $subsiteCtx.ExecuteQuery() 

             $pageInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.PublishingPageInformation  
             $pageInfo.Name = $pageName  
             $pageInfo.PageLayoutListItem = $pageLayout  
             $page = $pubWeb.AddPublishingPage($pageInfo)  
             $subsiteCtx.Load($page)  
             $subsiteCtx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample test script, create publishing page in sub site.

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll"

$siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Developer"
$UserName = "lee@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "pw" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials =New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $Password) 

# - Uncomment above lines incase of SharePoint online 
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl) 
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials 

$rootWeb = $ctx.Site.RootWeb
$ctx.Load($rootWeb)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$mpList = $rootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Master Page Gallery")
$camlQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$camlQuery.ViewXml = '<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" /><Value Type="Text">ArticleLeft.aspx</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>'
$items = $mpList.GetItems($camlQuery)
$ctx.Load($items)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$tpLayoutItem = $items[0]
$ctx.Load($tpLayoutItem)

$web = $ctx.Site.OpenWeb("test")
$pubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($ctx, $web)
$ctx.Load($pubWeb)

$pagesList = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages")

$pubPageInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.PublishingPageInformation
$pubPageInfo.Name ="testplaa.aspx"
$pubPageInfo.PageLayoutListItem = $tpLayoutItem
$pubPage = $pubWeb.AddPublishingpage($pubPageInfo)

$ctx.Load($pubPage)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$listItem = $pubPage.get_listItem()
$ctx.Load($listItem)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Code is same but i'm unable to create  publishing page in subsite ,getting error "The given key was not present in the dictionary."In sitecollection level i'm able to create pages without error.